# Insert override generated code at caret position?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm quite the happy user of eclipse mars, it gets the job done.

One thing that does bug me a bit is that when i use "Override/Implements methods.." feature the generate code is always put at the end of the java source file.

Is it possible to add the generate code at the cursor/caret position?

Comment: @guy that was indeed also my impression, but i did a few searches through the Preferences (caret, override, insert and similar terms) before posting here, but couldn't find the option. I could be just overlooking the thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify after which method to put it using Insertion point.

Example with Getters/Setters

[image]

Override/Implements dialog:

[image]

Comment: That is the 'Generate Getters and Setters' dialog, not the 'Override/Implement Methods' dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 its the same thing

Comment: No it isn't, there is a different dialog for override.

Comment: Thumbs up @guy ! This works flawlessly, i was looking in the wrong (in preferences dialog) place.

Comment: @greg-449 it indeed is different, but it doesn't really matter in this case, cause the override/implements methods dialog has the same "insertion point" field.

Comment: @greg-449 I added the second dialog, they both use insertion point to choose where to insert the method

Comment: Please note that it still randomly doesn't work, although it seems to be a bug in lombok, i created a ticket: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1002